# Google play| App status has been rejected and wasn't published due to this policy. Reason:Your app’s content rating is incorrect

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play, admob, google-play-console

I have a flutter app which is as simple as containing stories in different languages which is stored in a firebase cloud firestore.

**Contained in app:**

1. Different language(Kannada)
2. png's and svg's from **undraw.co**
3. Abusing language(English words in database ex: "go to hell", "fu***** bi***", etc
4. **Admobs** banner and rewarded video ads are added in app
5. **Google sign in** method using flutter package
6. Using launch url and redirecting it to my personal **instagram link**

While publishing app in play store, I have submitted a questionnaire and made the app as **13+ rated**, and in the audience I provided age group for using the app is **13+**

But my app is rejected by play console with the below issues

```
 **About content ratings** Your app’s content rating is incorrect. Our content rating system includes official ratings from the International
 Age Rating Coalition (IARC) and is designed to help developers
 communicate locally relevant content ratings to users.

  **App status: Rejected**    Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to this policy issue. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to submit the content rating questionnaire again and answer all questions correctly. As your app contains offensive language, you will have to choose yes in the question that asks whether your app contains any potentially offensive language.

Comment: Thank you!! I made my app for 16+ rated.. now its fine